# How do I add a superscripted comma and a space in a ggplot2 axis tick label?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, superscript

I am trying to add superscripts to my y axis tick labels in ggplot2.  I want the labels to look like this:

ATRS2<sup>0m,0f</sup> (where the 0f and 0m are superscripted).  This produces an error that looks like this.

> Error in parse(text = levels(diff_30$Station)) :
> <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol
> 1: ATRS2^0m0f
> ^

I realize that what I am parsing is not an R expression of any sort, which is why it is failing.  But how do I get this to work?  There must be some way.

My code to create the label looks like this:

```
paste(missing_df$Station,paste('^',missing_df$Precip_30_m,"m,",missing_df$TMin_30_f,"f",sep=''),sep='')
```

My ggplot code to plot and produce the labels looks like this.

```
plot + scale_y_discrete(labels = parse(text = levels(diff_30$Station)))
```

I've tried using this, but that fails.  I've looked at bquote, which might work, but that syntax is confusing me even more.

```
plot + scale_y_discrete(labels = expression(parse(text = levels(diff_30$Station))))
```

Any help would be wonderful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if the next piece of code does the trick you are looking for:

```
data("iris")

#vector from factor levels 
strtest <- levels(iris$Species)

#We build the "label" and leave the result as a list
labels <- lapply(strtest, function(x) bquote(.(x)^'0m,0f'))

#Plotting
ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species))+
  geom_point() +
  #we use do.call to "apply" function 'expression' to each element of the list label
  scale_y_discrete(labels=do.call(expression,labels))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Sorry it took me so long to see it.  It works great!

Comment: No worries mate :) Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

How is bquote() confusing you exactly? Because of the digit behind the hat of the formula, put your superscript in quotes! Tha should solve your problems...

```
library(ggplot2)
data("mtcars")
mtcars %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  ylab(bquote(~ATRS2^"0m"))+
  xlab(bquote(~ATRS2^"0f"))
```

[image]

I clearly misread the question before and can't really help on that one. actually I have some problems really getting the problem, without having seen the data. For superscripts in the ticks, you could maybe give scales::label_math a try? Still not addressing your problem directly, at least I got some superscripts with the variable's levels though ;-)

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- tibble::tibble(x = as.factor(sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace = TRUE)), y = sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE))
data %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = levels(data$x), , labels = scales::label_math(expr = "ATRS2"^{.x}, format = force))
```

Comment: No need for exclamation points here.  Also, I did not say the superscripts were supposed to go on separate axes.  They need to be on the same label, and go on the axis tick mark labels.